# How to get and save a client's IP address, location, and other data In PHP?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am using this code to get the information of a client. This code is working, but it gives some errors. Please check my code, and help me to correct it. And furthermore: how to store user data into MySQL? I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Bdh.jpg) will be highly thankful to you.Error are given below.
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$loc in Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$org in Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$city in Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$region in Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$country in Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$loc in Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$org in Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$city in Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$region in Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$country in

```
<?php
  // This program generates a web pages that gets 
  // the user's information, saves it to a file, 
  // and displays it on the web page.
  // Created by Mitchell Robinson.
  // 27 July, 2014.
  
  // Name of the ip address log.
  $outputWebBug = 'iplog.csv';

  // Get the ip address and info about client.
  @ $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/json"));
  @ $hostname=gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  
  // Get the query string from the URL.
  $QUERY_STRING = preg_replace("%[^/a-zA-Z0-9@,_=]%", '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  
  // Write the ip address and info to file.
  @ $fileHandle = fopen($outputWebBug, "a");
  if ($fileHandle)
  {
    $string ='"'.$QUERY_STRING.'","' // everything after "?" in the URL
      .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'","' // ip address
      .$hostname.'","' // hostname
      .$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'","' // browser and operating system
      .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'","' // where they got the link for this page
      .$details->loc.'","' // latitude, longitude
      .$details->org.'","' // internet service provider
      .$details->city.'","'  // city
      .$details->region.'","' // state
      .$details->country.'","' // country
      .date("D dS M,Y h:i a").'"' // date
      ."\n"
      ;
     $write = fputs($fileHandle, $string);
    @ fclose($fileHandle);
  }

  $string = '<code>'
    .'<p>'.$QUERY_STRING.'</p><p>IP address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'</p><p>Hostname:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    .$hostname.'</p><p>Browser and OS:&nbsp;'
    .$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'</p><p>'
    .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'</p><p>Coordinates:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    .$details->loc.'</p><p>ISP provider:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    .$details->org.'</p><p>City:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    .$details->city.'</p><p>State:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    .$details->region.'</p><p>Country:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    .$details->country.'</p><p>Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    .date("D dS M,Y h:i a").'</p></code>'
    ;

  echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Who Am I?</title></head><body>';
  echo $string;
  echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

Comment: **but giving some errors**, what error give you ?, show us .

Comment: Please paste the error

Comment: @GNassro i have already attached image errors please check it..

Comment: i suggest you to delete the @ symbole, to check if there is other error

Comment: Please edit your Question and add clarifications. Do not provide those in comments.

Comment: @Scratte plz check my question now

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

put this in your .htaccess file

php_flag display_errors off